# Quiz Multiple-Choice Field for Content Node to create quizzes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, content-type

I am looking for a module to generate multiple-choice questions, i.e. a repeatable field with one question and many possible answers, that I could add to my content-type. I have researched the Drupal website and couldn't find what I was looking for other than the 'Quiz' module for which there is no stable version release for D7 at this time.

I just need suggestions for modules that may achieve that goal or a start on where to look.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this just came out: http://drupal.org/project/exam!

Some folks have also used the [webform module](http://drupal.org/project/webform/) to create online tests/quizzes.  The only problem with using that module, though it's well established, is that all you get as a result is the submitted answers from your students.  If you are actually also hoping to give users feedback instantaneously (like -- grade them and display results online), you'd have to do some programming yourself.

I'd actually work with quiz (which you already mentioned) or exam and test those out, since they are made for that type of thing.  They may not be stable releases, but they may already have most of the features you want.  Also, the more folks use them, the faster they can get debugged.  If you notice any problems, just report them in the issues queue!  ;-)  That's the beauty of open-source.  We all chip in to test and fix.

Anyway, just wanted to mention the exam and webform modules....